# How to get userprofile in django 2.0

Tags: python, django, user-profile

I read a few post already, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the UserProfile of a user. I created a one to one field relationship when I create the User Profile. I thought I could just query the UserProfile as is, but I can't get it to work.

```
def profile_edit(request):
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'medium/profile_edit.html', {'user_profile_form': form,

                                                    'current_user': user})
```

Any thoughts? Here's my models.py and views

## models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank=True)
```

## views.py

```
def register_user(request):
registered = False

if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and user_profile_form.is_valid():
        new_user = user_form.save()
        new_user.set_password(new_user.password)
        new_user.save()

        new_user_profile = user_profile_form.save(commit=False)
        new_user_profile.user = new_user

        if 'avatar' in request.FILES:
            new_user_profile.avatar = request.FILES['avatar']

        new_user_profile.save()
        registered = True
    else:
        print(user_form.errors, user_profile_form.errors)
else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm()
return render(request, 'medium/registration.html', {
    'user_form': user_form,
    'user_profile_form': user_profile_form,
    'registered': registered
})
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where exactly are you having trouble with this code: what doesn't work, and what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Of course after 2 hours of googling, I finally figured it out.

I put a related_name on my Model and then added this in the view

```
def profile_edit(request):
user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

return render(request, 'medium/profile_edit.html', {
    'user_profile_form': user_profile_form,
    'user_form': user_form,
})
```

Comment: If you don’t set `related_name`, you can use the default: `request.user.userprofile`.